# Yii2. Не обновляются/не публикуются ресурсы (web/assets)

Tags: yii2

На одном проекте случилась такая странная ситуация:

**Перестали обновляться файлы css в web/assets.**

Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.

- ресурсы публикуются через $sourcePath
- раньше все работало
- права на web/assets вроде достаточные 775 (тут не уверен, поскольку не админ)
- в директории создаются поддиректории типа 1c5944bf, 2f827e2a...

но, суть проблемы:

```
* очистил полностью web/assets
* изменил css файл во внутренней папке проекта
* зашел на сайт. все ок. новые правила css видны. внутри web/assets появились 1c5944bf, 2f827e2a... полет отличный
* снова изменил файл css
* !!!зашел на сайт. css файлы остались старые.!!!
* снова почистил папку web/assets
* зашел на сайт. все ок. новые правила css видны. внутри web/assets появились 1c5944bf, 2f827e2a... полет отличный
```

такое уже было давно на одном проекте - тогда так и не понял в чем проблема, и вот снова.

по сути файлы во временных(random-ных) папках не обновляются до тех пор пока не стереть всю временную(random-ную) папку

подскажите, кто сталкивался, где копать

---

UPDATE: забыл уточнить. я и сам могу найти поиском такие опции как 'linkAssets' => true, 'forceCopy' => true...

интересует именно что могло случиться. ведь все работало и без этих опций. я стараюсь понять где что я мог зацепить, что все перестало обновляться

Comment: попробуйте такой способ: в `composer.json` проверьте права на папку, должно быть 0777 в setPermissions, удалите файл `composer.lock` и сделайте `composer install`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял проблема известна разработчикам фреймворка и будет решена в следующей версии.

Суть проблемы: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8197

Причина: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620684/directory-last-modified-date

временный костыль

```
$config['components']['assetManager']['hashCallback'] = function($path){
    $mostRecentFileMTime = 0;
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isFile() && $fileinfo->getMTime() > $mostRecentFileMTime) {
            $mostRecentFileMTime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
        }
    }
    $path = (is_file($path) ? dirname($path) : $path) . $mostRecentFileMTime;
    return sprintf('%x', crc32($path . Yii::getVersion()));
};
```